# Convert multiple VTT files into one SRT file with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, automation

```
06i1tkpe_cyberwork_and_the_american_dream_nola_cwad_00_h1-trimmed-captions_978_0.vtt
06i1tkpe_cyberwork_and_the_american_dream_nola_cwad_00_h1-trimmed-captions_978_1.vtt
06i1tkpe_cyberwork_and_the_american_dream_nola_cwad_00_h1-trimmed-captions_978_2.vtt
06i1tkpe_cyberwork_and_the_american_dream_nola_cwad_00_h1-trimmed-captions_978_3.vtt

...

06i1tkpe_cyberwork_and_the_american_dream_nola_cwad_00_h1-trimmed-captions_978_19.vtt
```

I have 20 `.vtt` files on my laptop and I want to merge and convert those files into one `.srt` file.

Those files have already the right timing and every file contains this sentence in the beginning `WEBVTT X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:187507, LOCAL:00:00:00.000`.

I've already installed ffmpeg and Aegisub.

I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please add information what you tried to reach your goal in automating this. Code snippets, error messages you got etc. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1457395/edit) your question with this information as Superuser is not a scripting service and we need this information to help you.

Comment: I want to convert these 20 VTT files into one SRT file with the help of  ffmpeg. And the timing is right. I don't wanna delete this `WEBVTT X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:187507, LOCAL:00:00:00.000.` 20 times and paste these 20 time in Aegisub